# What layout do I use for creating a form in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-gridlayout

I need to create a layout exactly like in the picture. What layout can I use? If I use LinearLayout, I can't add the icons in front of the text fields without using so many nested LinearLayouts. With RelativeLayout, I don't know how to make the Textfields start always on the same height. With the Grid layout, I don't know how to put two Textfields in one row, like for phone and area.

[image: Form Layout]

Comment: At first, you shouldn't use RelativeLayout at all. Use ConstraintLayout instead.

Comment: ConstraintLayout for sure! That will make life easy!